# Strange characters in YAP (DVI Previewer) Dialog Boxes

Tags: miktex, yap

A colleague using MiKTeX 6300 and WinEdt 10.2 together with YAP to view DVIs is having problems with font encoding in dialog boxes produced by YAP, two samples of which are given below. These cropped up only recently (until then everything was working fine).

[image: YAP Dialog]

[image: YAP Dialog2]

This happens regardless of the source file used (the source in the two samples above is http://physics.clarku.edu/sip/tutorials/TeX/intro.html). The menus of YAP are in English and display fine (as shown), and usability is not impacted except for the "Goto Page" dialog box, which is illegible.

Can someone pinpoint a possible source for this, and possible fixes, short of uninstalling/reinstalling MiKTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TX SX! Very strange… I suppose you mean WinEdt 10.2 (there never was a version 2). Perhaps only uninstall and reinstall `miktex-yap-bin-(x64)-2.9` with `MiKTeX Package Manager`?

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I mistyped WinEdt 10.2, and have edited my question to correct this.

Comment: If reinstalling miktex-yap-bin doesn't help you should imho ask in the miktex bug tracker. Christian Schenk will probably better know which font is used here and what could break it.